# WebApi how to pass a collection of objects with a HttpGet

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-get

I 'm looking on how can I pass a collection of complex object `TradeFilter` using a Get method. Using a Post method is not the best approach cause it will not respect the Rest principals (use a Post when you need to insert/update).

The code I used :

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/trade/customtrade")]
public string GetCustomTrade([FromUri]List<TradeFilter> filter)
{
    return "value";
}

public class TradeFilter
{
    public int Ref { get; set; }

    public string DateAsOf { get; set; }
}
```

The Url I use that gives me always 0 objects :

http://localhost:60704/api/trade/customtrade?Ref=5&DateAsOf=15/1/2014

Comment: Use JSON. Jquery has a helpful Stringify function to this. Or just your a client side json formater.

Comment: Something like `api/trade/customtrade?filter[0].Property1=one&filter[0].Property2=23&filter[1].Property1=two&filter[1].Property2=33`. From docs: _For those types such as Collection types, model binding looks for matches to parameter_name[index] or just [index]_

Comment: I would go with custom model binder which would allow something like `filter=customer eq 42,total gt 100`

Comment: @Fabio it works fine with your proposition, is there such a formater that allow me to create a json and convert it to such a format

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Any example of custom model binding

Comment: Not sure, you can seriously consider to create custom model binder - which accept json format. [Model binders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#model-binders)

Comment: Solution from @Fabio is the best practice, but if you want json, just do a string parameter and deserialize it in the method

Comment: @Fabio do we have some restriction with url size

Comment: If you're getting the list from a html `form`, then you could do `$('form').serialize()` to get the data in the way @Fabio suggested.(the name attributes of  form inputs should be proper). But `List` of complex objects in a `GET` seems like a really bad idea and might lead to unnecessary bugs in the future.

Comment: @MoezRebai, yes url maximum length have restrictions defined by browsers and servers. They are different with different behaviour and possible configurable